# How to write '<' and '>' to XML file

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to edit `.xml` file using this code:

```
subReportPath = "/xxx/runtime/uploads/report/" ;
parameterChild.setText("<"+"![CDATA["+subReportPath+"]]>");
```

Here's the result:

```xml
<defaultValueExpression>&lt;![CDATA[/home/amira/xxx/runtime/uploads/report/]]&gt;</defaultValueExpression>
```

How to write the `<` and the `>` in the XML file?

Comment: Can you show us a little bit more of your code? What libraries are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no need for you to manually specify a CDATA section. The XML library will automatically take care of any escaping for you.

That said, if you really have a need for that content to be wrapped in a CDATA section, you can do so like this:

```
parameterChild.setContent(new CDATA(subReportPath));
```

This is assuming you're using JDOM - using the [org.jdata.CDATA](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs.1.1/org/jdom/CDATA.html) class. If you're using another XML library it would help if you told us what it is.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to add a CDATA element into your XML use the appropriate Node type instead of plain text, e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#createCDATASection(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use the [Character Entity References](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). So, for example:

```
< = &lt;
> = &gt;
```